# how to send email with alternate views either plain text or HTml templates.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, alternateview

I want to send email with alternate views either plain text or html template, i have used code from the following link
[aspnet-sending-email-both-in-html-and-plain-text](http://www.search-this.com/2009/02/05/aspnet-sending-email-both-in-html-and-plain-text/) but i dont know why its not working for me.. my code is:.

```
  public void EmailSendingWithBothHTMLAndPlainText()
{
    // CREATE EMAIL
    // first we create a plain text version and set it to the AlternateView
    // then we create the HTML version
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

    msg.From = new MailAddress("visionstask@gmail.com");
    msg.Subject = "Event: testing";
    msg.To.Add("ram@tsgdev.net");

    // create a string to hold all email addresses
    StringBuilder sbEmailTo = new StringBuilder();
    sbEmailTo.Append("visionstask@gmail.com");

    //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxEmail2.Text)) { msg.To.Add(TextBoxEmail2.Text); sbEmailTo.Append(", " + TextBoxEmail2.Text); }
    //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxEmail3.Text)) { msg.To.Add(TextBoxEmail3.Text); sbEmailTo.Append(", " + TextBoxEmail3.Text); }
    //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxEmail4.Text)) { msg.To.Add(TextBoxEmail4.Text); sbEmailTo.Append(", " + TextBoxEmail4.Text); }
    //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxEmail5.Text)) { msg.To.Add(TextBoxEmail5.Text); sbEmailTo.Append(", " + TextBoxEmail5.Text); }



    //now create the HTML version
    MailDefinition message = new MailDefinition();
    message.BodyFileName = "RegisterUser.html";
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.From = "visionstask@gmail.com";
    message.Subject = "Zoo Event: " + "testing for HTML";

    //embed images for the email
    //EmbeddedMailObject emo = new EmbeddedMailObject();
    //emo.Path = @"~\Images\email\hdr_roar.gif";
    //emo.Name = "hdr";

    //EmbeddedMailObject emo2 = new EmbeddedMailObject();
    ////emo2.Path = @"~\Images\email\box_top.gif";
    //emo2.Name = "box_top";

    //message.EmbeddedObjects.Add(emo);
    //message.EmbeddedObjects.Add(emo2);

    //Build replacement collection to replace fields in email.htm file
    ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();
    replacements.Add("@Name", "Ram Singh");


    //now create mail message using the mail definition object
    //the CreateMailMessage object takes a source control object as the last parameter,
    //if the object you are working with is webcontrol then you can just pass "this",
    //otherwise create a dummy control as below.
    //System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msgHtml = message.CreateMailMessage(sbEmailTo.ToString(), replacements, new LiteralControl());

    //AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgHtml.Body, null, "text/html");


    // msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


    String plainEmail = "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='center'><table width='600' bgcolor='#f3f3f3' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td><img src='http://localhost:4823/WishIsDone/Images/emaillogo.png' style='margin-left: 50px;'alt='' /></td></tr><tr><td><table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' border='0' width='500' align='center' style='margin: auto; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px;' cellpadding='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td style='font-size: 18px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #008fbb;'>Registration</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td><table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' border='0' width='500' align='center' style='margin: auto; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 20px;'><tr><td>Hello @Name!</td></tr><tr><td style='font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'>Welcome to WishIsDone Website </td></tr><tr><td style='font-size: 12px; color: #008fbb; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'> <p>You have successfully registrated.</p> </td> </tr><tr><td style='font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #999;'><p>Verify your e-mail address to complete your registration by clicking the link:</p> <p><a href='#'>@link</a></p><p><strong style='color: #000; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>Note:</strong><span style='color: #333;'>please change your password after login.</span></p><table style='border-top: 1px dotted #999; margin: auto;' width='450'><tr><td style='font-size: 10px; color: #333;'><p>Regards,<br /> Wish Is Done Team</p></td></tr></table></td></tr> </table> </td></tr> <tr> <td style='font-size: 10px; color: #333; padding: 10px 50px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'> <p> For any queries or difficulties Contact:<br /> Email:<a href='#'>info@wishisdone.com</a><br /> Toll free: XXX-XXX-XXXX<br /> <a href='#'>www.wishisdone.com</a></p> </td></tr><tr><td><table style='border-top: 1px dotted #999; width: 500px; color: #333; margin: auto; font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'> <tr><td>Copyright &copy; 2012 wishisdone</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td> </tr></table>";

    //first we create the Plain Text part
    AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(plainEmail, null, "text/plain");
    msg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@gmail.com", "test");
    emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
    emailClient.Port = 587;
    emailClient.EnableSsl = true;
    //SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP"].ToString());
    //emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    //emailClient.EnableSsl = true;

    emailClient.Send(msg);
}
```

and i am getting the following outout in mail :

```
<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='center'><table width='600' bgcolor='#f3f3f3' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td><img src='http://localhost:4823/WishIsDone/Images/emaillogo.png' style='margin-left: 50px;'alt='' /></td></tr><tr><td><table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' border='0' width='500' align='center' style='margin: auto; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px;' cellpadding='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td style='font-size: 18px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #008fbb;'>Registration</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td><table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' border='0' width='500' align='center' style='margin: auto; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 20px;'><tr><td>Hello @Name!</td></tr><tr><td style='font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'>Welcome to WishIsDone Website </td></tr><tr><td style='font-size: 12px; color: #008fbb; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'> <p>You have successfully registrated.</p> </td> </tr><tr><td style='font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #999;'><p>Verify your e-mail address to complete your registration by clicking the link:</p> <p><a href='#'>@link</a></p><p><strong style='color: #000; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>Note:</strong><span style='color: #333;'>please change your password after login.</span></p><table style='border-top: 1px dotted #999; margin: auto;' width='450'><tr><td style='font-size: 10px; color: #333;'><p>Regards,<br /> Wish Is Done Team</p></td></tr></table></td></tr> </table> </td></tr> <tr> <td style='font-size: 10px; color: #333; padding: 10px 50px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'> <p> For any queries or difficulties Contact:<br /> Email:<a href='#'>info@wishisdone.com</a><br /> Toll free: XXX-XXX-XXXX<br /> <a href='#'>www.wishisdone.com</a></p> </td></tr><tr><td><table style='border-top: 1px dotted #999; width: 500px; color: #333; margin: auto; font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'> <tr><td>Copyright &copy; 2012 wishisdone</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td> </tr></table>
```

Please help me..i want to display it the well formatted way, because of that i want to use alternate views.

Comment: I'd take a look at the MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx it appears you have your HTML, plain text switched around

Comment: Here is an article that shows you how to [send email with C#](http://comfirm.se/send-email-with-csharp-dotnet/) (with a link to [AlternateViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use text/html as mime type when creating the alternate view:

```
AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(plainEmail, null, "text/html");
```

Like it´s done int this example:
[Alternate Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx)

Comment: You're calling the variable `plainView`, but it's html. Maybe `htmlView` would be better?

Answer (score -4):

please try this.
because the html body is didnt used in you document

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add("you@gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("you@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "PHR WORLD User Contacting You";

    string body = "<h1>Message from </h1><p>Simply awesome!</p>";
    body += "<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>";
    body += "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='center'><table width='600' bgcolor='#f3f3f3' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td><img src='http://localhost:4823/WishIsDone/Images/emaillogo.png' style='margin-left: 50px;'alt='' /></td></tr><tr><td><table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' border='0' width='500' align='center' style='margin: auto; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px;' cellpadding='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td style='font-size: 18px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #008fbb;'>Registration</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td><table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' border='0' width='500' align='center' style='margin: auto; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 20px;'><tr><td>Hello @Name!</td></tr><tr><td style='font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'>Welcome to WishIsDone Website </td></tr><tr><td style='font-size: 12px; color: #008fbb; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'> <p>You have successfully registrated.</p> </td> </tr><tr><td style='font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #999;'><p>Verify your e-mail address to complete your registration by clicking the link:</p> <p><a href='#'>@link</a></p><p><strong style='color: #000; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;'>Note:</strong><span style='color: #333;'>please change your password after login.</span></p><table style='border-top: 1px dotted #999; margin: auto;' width='450'><tr><td style='font-size: 10px; color: #333;'><p>Regards,<br /> Wish Is Done Team</p></td></tr></table></td></tr> </table> </td></tr> <tr> <td style='font-size: 10px; color: #333; padding: 10px 50px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'> <p> For any queries or difficulties Contact:<br /> Email:<a href='#'>info@wishisdone.com</a><br /> Toll free: XXX-XXX-XXXX<br /> <a href='#'>www.wishisdone.com</a></p> </td></tr><tr><td><table style='border-top: 1px dotted #999; width: 500px; color: #333; margin: auto; font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'> <tr><td>Copyright &copy; 2012 wishisdone</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td> </tr></table>";

    body += "</FONT></DIV></BODY></HTML>";
    body += " Sender Name: " + txtName.Text + "\n Sender Email: " + txtMail.Text + "\n Sender mobile: " + txtmobile.Text + "\n Subject:" + txtMessage.Text;
   mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("you@gmail.com", "password");
    //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
    smtp.Send(mail);
    ClearTextBoxes(Page);
    Label1.Text = "Thanks for contacting us";
}
```